# How are IP addresses assigned to ISP?

Tags: ip, allocation, delegation

I was wondering how IP address allocation works. Is it done vis reverse DNS, so the IP range is delegated to ISPs' DNS servers like domains are?

Answer (score 0):

They are allocated sort of manually by IANA, used by ISPs and propagated all over the Internet by routers with the help of interior (OSPF, RIP, IGRP) and exterior (BGP, EGP) routing protocols.

Comment: So are the ip ranges delegated from IANA to ISPs like normal domains ? using DNS for it 
 like reverse zones? or different technique is used ?